# How can i change user?(cmd, mariadb)

Tags: mariadb

I just wanna ask simple question.
Is there any method to change my user in cmd?

I mean, make user 'happy', and 'pizza' in mariadb.
 And log in through cmd.(using happy user) so i will type like this.

```
mysql -u happy -p mysql;
```

And here, I want to change user to 'pizza'.
(i want to use 'pizza' instead of 'happy')

My teacher said log out and relogin

```
Wq;
mysql -u pizza -p mysql
```

But I want to change my user at maria db. 
Is there any good computer instruction to use??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Plan A:  Have two cmd windows open, one for 'happy', one for 'pizza'.

Plan B:  Redesign the "users" so that one user has the permissions you need.